# Ramda: filtering an array against an array of items

Tags: ramda.js

I have a working function to filter the following array:

```
const arrayOne = [
    {
        node: {
            caseStudyFields: {
                filterTags: [
                    "Temperature control"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        node: {
            caseStudyFields: {
                filterTags: null
            }
        }
    },
    {
        node: {
            caseStudyFields: {
                filterTags: [
                    "Specialist manufacturing",
                    "Pharmaceuticals"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
]
const arrayTwo = [
    'Pharmaceuticals',
    'Specialist manufacturing',
    'Temperature control'
]

const fn = n => n.node.caseStudyFields.filterTags && 
n.node.caseStudyFields.filterTags.some(r => arrayTwo.includes(r))
    
return arrayOne.filter(fn)
```

This code works fine, but I wanted to convert it to Ramda (for fun). I've got so far in finding the path but I've become confused with the some and includes (any in Ramda?)

```
const filter = R.filter(
        R.pipe(
            R.path(['node', 'caseStudyFields', 'filterTags']),
        )
    );

return filter(arrayOne)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use R.pathOr to get the value at the path, and return and empty array if it's `null`. This will prevent filter from erroring when encountering the `null`.

Use R.any (Ramda's equivalent to `Array.some()`) with R.includes, curried with the array of `tags`, to find matching items:

```js
const { curry, filter, pipe, pathOr, any, includes, __ } = R

const filterByTags = curry((tags, arr) =>  
  filter(pipe(
    pathOr([], ['node', 'caseStudyFields', 'filterTags']),
    any(includes(__, tags))
  ))
(arr))

const arrayOne = [{"node":{"caseStudyFields":{"filterTags":["Temperature control"]}}},{"node":{"caseStudyFields":{"filterTags":null}}},{"node":{"caseStudyFields":{"filterTags":["Specialist manufacturing","Pharmaceuticals"]}}}]
const arrayTwo = ["Pharmaceuticals","Specialist manufacturing","Temperature control"]

const result = filterByTags(arrayTwo, arrayOne)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```